# How to priorize / change order of string breaking / wrapping to next line in HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, string

Consider this string:

```
"Word1 Word2 Word3"
```

As the screen width gets narrower, it will break first after "Word2" and 2nd before "Word2". I want these breaks to be swapped. The string should break 1st before Word2 and 2nd after "Word2":

First breaking:

```
Word1
Word2 Word3
```

(if it was only this, I could place a `&nbsp;` between Word2 and Word3, but ...)

2nd breaking:

```
Word1
Word2
Word3
```

Comment: Use separate spans for each phrase

Comment: @Paulie_D Very elegant idea. So the break will occur first outside of spans and later inside the spans.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the pseudo-class `::after` and employing:

```
content: '\a';
white-space: pre;
```

...in your CSS.

Here's an example:

At a max-width of 350px, you'll see your content as:

```
Word1
Word2
Word3
```

Once it reaches 400px, it will go to:

```
Word1
Word2 Word3
```

Beyond that, you'll see:

```
Word1 Word2 Word3
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  span:nth-child(1)::after {
    content: '\a';
    white-space: pre;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
  span:nth-child(2)::after {
    content: '\a';
    white-space: pre;
  }
}
```

```html
<span>Word1</span>
<span>Word2</span>
<span>Word3</span>
```